# elementary OS 5 Juno - No internet via Ethernet - Desktop - Intel I217-V

Tags: intel, internet, ethernet

Please help, I'm trying elementary for the first time and wired internet does work.
Under network settings it just keeps trying to connect, then says not connected.
My motherboard's lan chip is a Intel® Ethernet Connection I217-V

I guess Juno doesn't come packaged with the required drivers?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Resolved**
In turns out windows 10 wasn't 'letting go' of my NIC on shutdown, before booting into the Elementary live usb, so elementary couldn't connect to my router.

Switching off my PC by the PSU resolved it.